# How to get this form JSON UPDATED

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this json format it is for pictures and showing the picture name and the links of it different sizes  and i don't know how to get it using PHP

```
[{
    "name": "Deadpool",
    "url": {
        "small": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/small/deadpool.jpg",
        "medium": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/medium/deadpool.jpg",
        "large": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/large/deadpool.jpg"
    },
    "timestamp": "February 12, 2016"
},
{
    "name": "Batman vs Superman",
    "url": {
        "small": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/small/bvs.png",
        "medium": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/medium/bvs.png",
        "large": "http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/large/bvs.png"
    },
    "timestamp": "March 25, 2016"
}]
```

I know that json have Objects and Array of objects. Therefore i tried to insert some data but i can't reach the wanted format

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(0);
    require('C:\wamp\www\HiFootball\config.php');
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

        $query="select   player_image as 'player image ',team_logo as  'team logo'
 from team,player ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $rows = array();
    echo mysqli_error($conn);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($rows);

    ?>
```

And this is the result json

```
[
{
"player image ":"http:\/\/www.almrsal.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/02\/Lionel_Messi.jpg",
"team logo":"https:\/\/upload.wikimedia.org\/wikipedia\/en\/thumb\/5\/56\/Real_Madrid_CF.svg\/732px-Real_Madrid_CF.svg.png"
},
{
"player image ":"http:\/\/www.almrsal.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/02\/Lionel_Messi.jpg",
"team logo":"http:\/\/assets4.fcbarcelona.com\/images\/og-logo.cb6aeb6cb.png"
},
{
"player image ":"http:\/\/www.almrsal.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/02\/Lionel_Messi.jpg",
"team logo":"http:\/\/4.bp.blogspot.com\/-IL3G9zAGiNE\/VbwIM5znSeI\/AAAAAAAAoxw\/4AKy1E3g8Ko\/s1600\/adidas-manchester-united-15-16-kit-3.jpg"
},
{
"player image ":"http:\/\/i.telegraph.co.uk\/multimedia\/archive\/03542\/ronaldo-future_3542529b.jpg",
"team logo":"https:\/\/upload.wikimedia.org\/wikipedia\/en\/thumb\/5\/56\/Real_Madrid_CF.svg\/732px-Real_Madrid_CF.svg.png"
},
{
"player image ":"http:\/\/i.telegraph.co.uk\/multimedia\/archive\/03542\/ronaldo-future_3542529b.jpg",
"team logo":"http:\/\/assets4.fcbarcelona.com\/images\/og-logo.cb6aeb6cb.png"
},
{
"player image ":"http:\/\/i.telegraph.co.uk\/multimedia\/archive\/03542\/ronaldo-future_3542529b.jpg",
"team logo":"http:\/\/4.bp.blogspot.com\/-IL3G9zAGiNE\/VbwIM5znSeI\/AAAAAAAAoxw\/4AKy1E3g8Ko\/s1600\/adidas-manchester-united-15-16-kit-3.jpg"
}
]
```

If anyone can help me please ?!

Comment: what is a result of json_encode now?

Comment: @splash58 See The Updated Post Please

Comment: there is no information in your current data to build array you want. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes Sir, but i am following this tutorial [link]http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/

Comment: Show the columns you have in the two tables *team* and *player*. Because your query is not returning any name, timestamp, nor any different sized image urls. So it is impossible to return the JSON you mention at the start.